# What causes kAUGraphErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext error when calling DisposeAUGraph() in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, audio, audiotoolbox

I've got some code that plays a MIDI file using the AudioToolbox framework's `MusicPlayer`, `MusicSequence`, and `AUGraph`.

Some time after playback is complete, the code below is used to tidy up. This code runs without issues in iOSs 6–8.

However, in iOS 9, the call to `DisposeAUGraph` fails, returning the error code `kAUGraphErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext`.

The documentation for `DisposeAUGraph` is almost non-existent, but the documentation for the return code itself states:

> To avoid spinning or waiting in the render thread (a bad idea!), many of the calls to AUGraph can return: kAUGraphErr_CannotDoInCurrentContext. This result is only generated when you call an AUGraph API from its render callback. It means that the lock that it required was held at that time, by another thread. If you see this result code, you can generally attempt the action again - typically the NEXT render cycle (so in the mean time the lock can be cleared), or you can delegate that call to another thread in your app. You should not spin or put-to-sleep the render thread.

The code below is *not* being called from the `AUGraph`'s render callback — indeed, no such callback exists — the code is (currently, in my debug code) manually initiated by the user.

What is causing this error, and is there any way I can avoid it?

```
OSStatus result = MusicPlayerStop(g_player);

if (result != noErr)
    DebugLog("Error calling MusicPlayerStop");

UInt32 trackCount;
result = MusicSequenceGetTrackCount(g_sequence, &trackCount);
if (result != noErr)
    DebugLog("Error calling MusicSequenceGetTrackCount.");

while(trackCount > 0)
{
    MusicTrack track;
    result = MusicSequenceGetIndTrack (g_sequence, 0, &track);
    if (result != noErr)
        DebugLog("Error calling MusicSequenceGetIndTrack.");

    result = MusicSequenceDisposeTrack(g_sequence, track);
    if (result != noErr)
        DebugLog("Error calling MusicSequenceDisposeTrack.");

    result = MusicSequenceGetTrackCount(g_sequence, &trackCount);
    if (result != noErr)
        DebugLog("Error calling MusicSequenceGetTrackCount.");
}

result = DisposeMusicPlayer(g_player);
if (result != noErr)
    DebugLog("Error calling DisposeMusicPlayer.");
result = DisposeMusicSequence(g_sequence);
if (result != noErr)
    DebugLog("Error calling DisposeMusicSequence.");
result = DisposeAUGraph(g_processingGraph);
if (result != noErr)
    DebugLog("Error calling DisposeAUGraph.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked around this problem by rewriting our playback code to use the newer `AVMIDIPlayer`* instead of `MusicPlayer` et al, when running on iOS 9.

<sub>* available as of iOS 8</sub>